# Peel & stick vinyl plank adhesive squeeze out ...reoccurring issue

Tags: flooring, vinyl

I installed peel & stick vinyl plank over sheet vinyl three years ago.  Pleased with the look but continue to have adhesive squeeze out.  I use goo gone to remove the goo but it's back again every six weeks.  What can I use to stop the squeeze out from reoccurring?

Comment: Three years  seems excessive amount of time.  Peel and stick should usually only have a thin amount of adhesive.

Comment: Why is there _any_ adhesive with a peel-and-stick (self-adhesive) flooring product? This situation doesn't make sense to me.